# problems with text rotated in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I have a big problem , I save a picture with html2canvas but in my picture there are several element (text) in rotated but it does not work in canvas.

This is my code for generate my canvas:

```
    finalImgSrc = html2canvas($("#bou12"), {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
             $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

        }

}
```

This is my picture on my screen

http://hpics.li/648c063

and this my canvas picture

http://hpics.li/050aa24

I really need help for this.

---------EDIT----------

i save in the variable because i put into tcpdf in php with this code

```
var urlwrite = $('#img_val').val();

           $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,/
                        data: { urlwrite: urlwrite },
                        dataType: 'json', // dire que le type est en json
                        url: url+'/FunctionAdd/CSV2/PDFTest.php',
                        success:
                                function(data)
                                {

                                },

                    error: function(s){


                        alert("error")

                    }

                }, "json");
```

just the vertical text does nt work

this is my html code for the ID="#bou12"

```
<div id="bou12" style="height:500px;"><div id="imageParent" style="position:absolute;">

<img src="http://mad.cerp.be/cerp/V14/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ACCROCHE-CANNE-GRENOUILLE-OA889-631135.jpg" class="attachment-200x200 size-200x200 img-responsive" alt="SONY DSC" srcset="http://mad.cerp.be/cerp/V14/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ACCROCHE-CANNE-GRENOUILLE-OA889-631135.jpg 1205w, http://mad.cerp.be/cerp/V14/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ACCROCHE-CANNE-GRENOUILLE-OA889-631135-263x300.jpg 263w, http://mad.cerp.be/cerp/V14/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ACCROCHE-CANNE-GRENOUILLE-OA889-631135-768x875.jpg 768w, http://mad.cerp.be/cerp/V14/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ACCROCHE-CANNE-GRENOUILLE-OA889-631135-899x1024.jpg 899w" sizes="(max-width: 1205px) 100vw, 1205px" style="max-height: 500px;" height="1373" width="1205">

</div>
<div>
</div>
<div class="element1" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 85%; margin-top: 50%; writing-mode: vertical-lr; letter-spacing:  -3px; text-orientation: upright;" id="elementimg1">ezrezrezrez</div>
<div class="element2" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 1%; margin-top: 50%; writing-mode: vertical-lr; letter-spacing:  -3px; text-orientation: upright;" id="elementimg2">ezrzerezrezr</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no body can help me ?

Comment: issue is still open: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1258